# Rearranging cells in a cell array

Tags: matlab

I have a 16x1 cell array which I would like to rearrange:

```
{'T1' }
{'T10'}
{'T11'}
{'T12'}
{'T13'}
{'T14'}
{'T15'}
{'T16'}
{'T2' }
{'T3' }
{'T4' }
{'T5' }
{'T6' }
{'T7' }
{'T8' }
{'T9' }
```

How can I rearrange this to maintain the 16x1 structure, but sorted as

```
{'T1' }
{'T2' }
{'T3' }
{'T4' }
{'T5' }
{'T6' }
{'T7' }
{'T8' }
{'T9' }
{'T10'}
{'T11'}
{'T12'}
{'T13'}
{'T14'}
{'T15'}
{'T16'}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the strings to a vector of numbers (using [sscanf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html)) and use the indexes of the sorted numbers to rearrange the original cell array `A`:

```
[~, idx] = sort(sscanf([A{:}], 'T%d', numel(A)));
B = A(idx);
```

Answer (score 1):

`sortrows(yourarray)`

should do the job

Documentation: [sortrows](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.sortrows.html#d122e1207978)

Comment: Note that the original array is already sorted in lexicographic order. The question wants it to be sorted by number values.

Comment: I unfortunately was unable to replicate your solution. My actual data is of the form {'identical-stuff-T1}
{'identical-stuff-T10}
...

Comment: @rahnema1 Ah, I see. However, that's for a 2D cell array. I think for a cell vector as in this question it just leaves it as it is. See [here](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/QsFWoVo9xFBdQT3ECEQYGqjrgChD9VprheL8opKi/PJijQpNLmSVQEUQNTpgbagq//8HAA) (and I get the same results in Matlab). So `sortrows` doesn't work for this

Comment: @LuisMendo Your example is a row vector of cells so sortrows leaves it as it is. But when it is a column vector it should sort it in lexicographic order.

Comment: @rahnema1 Oops. You are right. And thus `sortrows` cannot be used for this

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the question by cutting the array and rearranging as follows:

```
inv = {16x1 data above}

tmpinv = inv([1, 9:16]);
tmpinv2 = inv(2:8);
inv = [tmpinv; tmpinv2];
```

However, I accepted rahnema1's answer as more robust solution.